# VBA String Array Syntax?

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Dim Subjects = New String() {"Health Care", "Tax", "Trade", "Technology and Privacy", "Energy and Natural Resources", "Oversight", "Domestic Issues", "Other"}
```

Receiving a syntax error, looking for an end to the statement, but as far as I can tell this should be proper syntax?

Comment: That's VB.NET syntax (or close to it at least). Are you writing this is VBA or VB.NET?

Comment: VBA, because I'm working in Word, but the syntax examples I was learning from were from learn.microsoft.com? Weird that they'd have VB.NET syntax examples.

Comment: VBA can be difficult to search for documentation on via doc.microsoft.com these days. You need to make sure that you don't see `.NET` in the page header. TBH, you're probably just better off searching here on SO or using a non-MS site for documentation.

Comment: Dang okay, thank you!

Comment: You need to learn to use the F1 key.  In the VBA IDE put the cursor on a keyword and press F1. This will take you to the MS help page for that keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim Subjects()
Subjects = Array("Health Care", "Tax", "Trade", "Technology and Privacy", "Energy and Natural Resources", "Oversight", "Domestic Issues", "Other")
```